# Bootstrap way of binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I was looking at bootstrap ['dropdown'](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/dropdown.js) module, and couldn't wrap my head around something.

Based on that code, the module needs to be explicitly initiated by calling it, e.g

```
$(element).dropdown({options..})
```

and yet, if you just give any element an attribute with [data-toggle="dropdown"]

the module in question kicks in, never entering the Constructor / Plugin functions.

Can someone explain this voodoo to me?

Comment: In the top of the script:  var Dropdown = function (element) { $(element).on('click.bs.dropdown', this.toggle) }
 
above that is the var for the toggle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Answer:

http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names

> An event name can be qualified by event namespaces that simplify removing or triggering the event. For example, "click.myPlugin.simple" defines both the myPlugin and simple namespaces for this particular click event. A click event handler attached via that string could be removed with .off("click.myPlugin") or .off("click.simple") without disturbing other click handlers attached to the elements. Namespaces are similar to CSS classes in that they are not hierarchical; only one name needs to match. Namespaces beginning with an underscore are reserved for jQuery's use.

Bootstrap are binding the click event using "event name-spacing". line (816 I believe)

```
.on('click.bs.dropdown.data-api', toggle, Dropdown.prototype.toggle)
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap uses jQuery, it will have a selector built in like:

```
 $("[data-toggle='dropdown']").dropdown();
```

thus targeting any elements with a `data-target` attribute with a value of `dropdown`

Comment: Where does that happens ? behind the scene or explicitly somewhere ?

Comment: search for this line `var toggle   = '[data-toggle="dropdown"]'` at https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.js

Comment: That's true, if you continue to read on you'll see the line `$(toggle).each(function () {....` that's where the "voodoo" happens

Comment: Are you kidding me? That's inside the clearMenus() function which gets called only on 'click.bs.dropdown.data-api' which requires the plugin to be initiated in order to even exist.. That's not the answer

Comment: Sorry, I just skimmed the code, it seems `data = new Dropdown(this)` is where the dropdown is actually created

Comment: I appreciate the effort. That's not the answer as well. the line of code you posted is only called when the Plugin function is called, meaning only during invoking via $(element).dropdown()

Comment: var Dropdown = function (element) {
$(element).on('click.bs.dropdown', this.toggle)
}